# Add spaces to infront of a string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

I want to add spaces (" ") infront of a string (like white spaces). this is the length of the spaces

```
 int spaces_needed=((36-[[dicBusinessDetails objectForKey:@"ResturantName"] length]))/2;
```

What I want is to create a string like this

```
 NSString stringWithFormat:@"               %@",[dicBusinessDetails objectForKey:@"ResturantName"];
```

But the spaces should **NOT** be fixed as above, but variable length of **int spaces_needed**.

*Actual reason for doing this is to center align a string in a receipt*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might like `NSString`'s `stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex`

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                             [@" " stringByPaddingToLength:spaces_needed withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0]
                             [dicBusinessDetails objectForKey:@"ResturantName"]];
```